# Multiple classes in multiple divs

Tags: html, css

I have this html with 6 divs:

```
    <div class="hisclass1 hisclass2 myclass hisclass3">
        <div class="herclass1 herclass2"> <!-- 2nd div -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hisclass1 hisclass2">
        <div class="herclass1 herclass2">
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="hisclass2 hisclass3">
        <div class="herclass1 herclass2 herclass3">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to change the height of ONLY 2ND div using CSS.

I don't want to use this

```
.hisclass1.hisclass2.myclass.hisclass3 herclass1.herclass2{}
```

because actually there are 20+ classes written the first div in the source.

How can I change the height of the 2nd div using `myclass` and classes of 2nd div (i.e. `herclass1` and `herclass2`?

Comment: Which div exactly is it that you want to change? There's multiple ways to interpret "of ONLY 2ND div", especially since the example you said you "don't want to use" doesn't apply to anything in your example

Comment: Perhaps put an HTML comment inside the div you want to select, like `<!-- This one -->`.

Comment: Speaking as a consultant who is often hired to clean up messes that include code like that, please refrain from following the advice from @DrManishLataa-ManoharJoshi. Inline CSS is brittle and hard to maintain, and under few circumstances is it warranted to use `!important`.

Comment: `.myclass .herclass1 { height: xx }` ? That seems what you want.

Comment: @j08691 I has made a mistake in the question. Sorry i corrected it. Also, found the answer as suggested by Joundill and disinfor. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.myclass .herclass1.herclass2 {
    height: 50px; /* Your height here */
}
```

You need to use a space between the class selectors, or else they're all applying to the same element.

Your example:

```css
hisclass1.hisclass2.myclass.hisclass3.herclass1.herclass2
```

Is trying to match an element which looks like this:

```html
<hisclass1 class="hisclass2 myclass hisclass3 herclass1 herclass2">
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked. I made a mistake in the question. I'll edit it. There will be space as suggested by you. Also, i don't have enough reputation to upvote else would have done. Thanks again for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood the question correctly.

Try this:

```
.myclass > *, .myclass + * > * {}
```